# variable number of arguments in constructor of int

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, new-operator, codepad

I wrote the following code snippet which resulted in compilation errors when executed on 
[codepad.org](http://codepad.org/BnLGt7VM)

```
int main()
{
int *p = new int(5,6,7);
return 0;
}
```

I was passing 3 number of arguments to constructor of int while dynamically allocating memory for it.(which should not work according to me).

But when I executed the same code in visual studio 2010 compiler it is compiling and initializing the value with the last argument. Why is this working like this?

Answer (score 1):

VS2010 is invoking commo operator and rightly assigning the last value.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator

For gcc try this

```
int main()
{
 int *p = new int((5,6,7));
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But why it is not working with gcc compiler?

Comment: i am trying to figure out

Answer (score 0):

VS2010 is non-conforming (surprise). The `(5,6,7)` in `new int(5,6,7)` is a *new-initializer*. According to C++11 §5.3.4/15:

> A *new-expression* that creates an object of type `T` initializes that object as follows:
>
> - If the *new-initializer* is omitted, the object is default-initialized (8.5); if no initialization is performed, the object has indeterminate value.
> - Otherwise, the *new-initializer* is interpreted according to the initialization rules of 8.5 for direct-initialization.

and §8.5/13 states:

> If the entity being initialized does not have class type, the *expression-list* in a parenthesized initializer shall be a single expression.

The *expression-list* in your example `5,6,7` has multiple expressions, so compilers should diagnose this as an error.

Comment: I think that 'single expression' is being treated as comma operator , I think which may be a right behaviour , I am not sure though.

Comment: @AnandRathi It's not a single expression, it's multiple expressions separated by a comma - it would have to be for the comma operator to even apply. I agree with you that VS2010 is interpreting this new-initializer in that way, but it's clearly non-conforming behavior.